# Responsive component in vueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, responsive

I'm migrating my jQuery PDFViewer to vueJS.

Right now, I'm calling my component thanks to these lines:

```
<div class="card-body" id="bodyContainer">
    <pdf-viewer :url="fileUrl"></pdf-viewer>
</div>
```

I would like that my pdf-viewer always uses the maximum width it has available to display the PDF.

The issue is, I need to be noticed each time the maximum width available has been updated.

How could I do that using VueJS?

Right now I have:

```
mounted: function() {
    this.containerWidth = this.$el.clientWidth;
}
```

But it's not really working since clientWidth is being updated after mounted has been called.

Comment: Use a watcher on variable which is changing.
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-watch-the-height-change-dom-of-an-element-in-vuejs/21290/4
This might help you.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I'm using to detect any width change.
I'm using a function found on another post on SO.

```
// Additional function to detect resizes
function ResizeSensor(element, callback)
{
    let zIndex = parseInt(getComputedStyle(element));
    if(isNaN(zIndex)) { zIndex = 0; };
    zIndex--;

    let expand = document.createElement('div');
    expand.style.position = "absolute";
    expand.style.left = "0px";
    expand.style.top = "0px";
    expand.style.right = "0px";
    expand.style.bottom = "0px";
    expand.style.overflow = "hidden";
    expand.style.zIndex = zIndex;
    expand.style.visibility = "hidden";

    let expandChild = document.createElement('div');
    expandChild.style.position = "absolute";
    expandChild.style.left = "0px";
    expandChild.style.top = "0px";
    expandChild.style.width = "10000000px";
    expandChild.style.height = "10000000px";
    expand.appendChild(expandChild);

    let shrink = document.createElement('div');
    shrink.style.position = "absolute";
    shrink.style.left = "0px";
    shrink.style.top = "0px";
    shrink.style.right = "0px";
    shrink.style.bottom = "0px";
    shrink.style.overflow = "hidden";
    shrink.style.zIndex = zIndex;
    shrink.style.visibility = "hidden";

    let shrinkChild = document.createElement('div');
    shrinkChild.style.position = "absolute";
    shrinkChild.style.left = "0px";
    shrinkChild.style.top = "0px";
    shrinkChild.style.width = "200%";
    shrinkChild.style.height = "200%";
    shrink.appendChild(shrinkChild);

    element.appendChild(expand);
    element.appendChild(shrink);

    function setScroll()
    {
        expand.scrollLeft = 10000000;
        expand.scrollTop = 10000000;

        shrink.scrollLeft = 10000000;
        shrink.scrollTop = 10000000;
    };
    setScroll();

    let size = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    let currentWidth = size.width;
    let currentHeight = size.height;

    let onScroll = function()
    {
        let size = element.getBoundingClientRect();

        let newWidth = size.width;
        let newHeight = size.height;

        if(newWidth != currentWidth || newHeight != currentHeight)
        {
            currentWidth = newWidth;
            currentHeight = newHeight;

            callback();
        }

        setScroll();
    };

    expand.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
    shrink.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
};
</script>
```

And here is my mounted function, updating the properties when needed, with a `setTimeout` in order to redraw the PDF when I'm sure the resize is over.

```
mounted: function() {
    this.containerWidth = this.$el.clientWidth;

    var _ = this;
    _.fetchPDF();

    var resizeTimer;
    new ResizeSensor(this.$el, function()
    {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);

        resizeTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            if(_.containerWidth != container.clientWidth){
                _.containerWidth = container.clientWidth;
            }
        }, 125)
    });

},
```

It might not be the best solution, so feel free to add yours if needed